# Inserting an element within jQuery Validation plugin's error template

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation, jquery-validate

I'm utilizing the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) for my form. It lets you change the **errorElement** and wrap the errorElement using with the **wrapper** option. But, I want to insert an element *within* errorElement like this:

`<label class="error"><em></em>Error message goes here</label>`

Is there an easy way to accomplish inserting the **em** tag?

I've tried prepending the em tag using the errorPlacement option (see below), but it seems the plugin is replacing the contents of errorElement afterwards.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.prepend('<em/>');
        error.insertBefore(element);
    }
});
```

I've also tried prepending the em tag using the showErrors option (see below). Again, it seems the plugin is replacing the contents of errorElement afterwards.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        for (var i = 0; i < errorList.length; i++) {
            var error = errorList[i],
                $label = this.errorsFor(error.element),
                $element = $(error.element);

            if ($label.length && $label.find('em').length == 0) {
                $label.prepend('<em/>');
            }
        }

        this.defaultShowErrors();
    }
});
```

I've also tried modifying the plugin so that when the error element is generated, the <em> tag is prepended. That works until I focus on a form element that has an error, after which the *em* tag is removed. (It's doing this because jQuery validation is constantly updating the contents of the error element as I focus and/or type in the field, therefore erasing my *em* tag added at error-element creation.)

Comment: This isn't really a solution to your problem, so I won't add it as an answer, but couldn't you just do `label.error { font-style: italic; }` in your CSS?

Comment: I'm not trying to italicize the error in general. I want to prepend or append an element (doesnt have to be em) to the error message. The problem is jquery validation keeps overwriting all the html within the error element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `showErrors` function to customize how errors are shown:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        if (errorList.length < 1) {
            // clear the error if validation succeeded
            $('label.error').remove();
            return;
        }
        $.each(errorList, function(index, error) {
            $(error.element).next('label.error').remove();
            $(error.element).after(
                $('<label/>')
                    .addClass('error')
                    .append($('<em/>').text('this is some em'))
                    .append(error.message)
            );
        });
    }
});
```

You can [see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/pSQPH/1/).

Comment: Almost. However, the error is not removed after satisfying the requirements.

Comment: @simshaun, I've updated my answer to include a test allowing to clear the error messages if validation succeeds (`errorList.length < 1`) in the `showErrors` callback. I've also updated the jsfiddle live demo.

Comment: Great approach, this helped me out

Answer (score 5):

I tried Darin's solution but faced two issues :

- With multiple fields, the error messages were not correctly removed when fields went valid.
- I couldn't use the `success` callback to change the error label to an 'Ok' label

I ended up with the following code that modify the error message before calling the default behaviour with `defaultShowErrors`

```
$('#my_form').validate({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    var i, elements;
    for(i = 0; errorList[i]; i++) {
        errorList[i].message = "<em> " + errorList[i].message + "</em>"
    }
    this.defaultShowErrors()    
    }
});
```

Comment: +1. Much simpler and more usable than the accepted answer + works with multiple fields

Comment: Although I used and like this solution (thanks) it does have an inefficiency.   The validation is really populating the messages twice.  If you comment out the call to this.defaultShowErrors() you will see the messages appearing without the customization, then call the defaultShowErrors and the are repopulated with the customized messages.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this by modifying the plugin, but will accept any (efficient) solution posted that doesn't involve modifying it.

What I did was add two new options, **appendToError** and **prependToError** to the plugin. Whatever is specified in these options will always be appended or prepended within the error element.

https://github.com/simshaun/jquery-validation/commit/bff7ba55d1d60ee0bac033989256a932185e7a97

(After learning a bit more about the plugin's inner workings, I don't think there is any possible way of doing what I want without modifying it, short of implementing something extremely inefficient.)