# jQuery Validation for select is conflicting with Bootstraps Chosen-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

The select box in my application is conflicting with chosen-select. below is a sample code.

**HTML**

```
    <form name="test1" id="test">
        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pwd">Course code:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <select name="search_course" data-placeholder="Select Courses"  id="search_course" class="chosen-select form-control" tabindex="8" style="width:60% !important;" <?php
//                            if ($readOnly) {
//                                echo 'readonly';
//                            }
                            ?>> <option value=""> Select</option>
                                        <?php
                                        if (!empty($courses)) {
                                            foreach ($courses as $values) {
                                                ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $values['idvs_crs_id']; ?>" <?php
                                        if ($values['idvs_crs_id'] == $post_values['search_course']) {
                                            echo 'selected';
                                            $selected_course_name = $values['idvs_crs_code'] . ' - ' . $values['idvs_crs_title'];
                                            $selected_course_code = $values['idvs_crs_code'];
                                        };
                                        ?> ><?php echo $values['idvs_crs_code'] . ' - ' . $values['idvs_crs_title']; ?></option>   
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" });
$("#test1").validate({
        onkeyup: false,

rules : {
   search_course:{
      required: true,
}
},
messages: {
    search_course: {
        required: "Please select a course code"
    },
}
});
```

To solve this i searched stackoverflow and found a solution to put the following

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" });
```

I added that just above the `.validate` and got it working but the problem is the error is misaligned and the select box gets shifted to make space for the error . The error should have been below the select box. is there any solution to solve this. Below is a screenshot of the issue i'm facing.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us the html too?

Comment: it will be very lengthy. is it fine?

Comment: Show us only the relevant html for this form

Comment: i've updated above with only one select. please check

Comment: Where does the "Please select a course code" markup is generated? I don't see it anywhere...

Comment: That happens in validate. i"ve updated now

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to change the error place on HTML by editing the `showErrors` method.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        if (errorList.length < 1) {
            // clear the error if validation succeeded
            $('label.error').remove();
            return;
        }
        $.each(errorList, function(index, error) {
            $(error.element).next('label.error').remove();
            $(error.element).after(
                $('<label/>')
                    .addClass('error')
                    .append($('<em/>').text('this is some em'))
                    .append(error.message)
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Check a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4698866/4737729).

Can you share the outputted HTMl to adapt the function to your markup?

===

This answer is from Darin Dimitrov. Check the full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4698866/4737729)